# Fortran runtime error: Bad real number

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a code as enclosed below. It is supposed to read a binary file and produce a special format. (This code is a part of siesta code.) However, I receive the following error when I execute the code:

```
At line 127 of file grid2cube.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 0 of list input
```

The fortran compiler and flags that I have compiled the main code are:

> FC= /usr/local/bin/mpif90 
>   FFLAGS=-g -O2 FPPFLAGS= -DMPI
>   -DFC_HAVE_FLUSH -DFC_HAVE_ABORT LDFLAGS=

This code is also compiled with the same flag:

> /usr/local/bin/mpif90          -c -g -O2     grid2cube.f
>   /usr/local/bin/mpif90           -o grid2cube grid2cube.o

I also change "-O2" to "-O1" and "O0" and recompiled everything. But the same error was produced.Besides I am using mpich-3.0.4 and gfortran as the base.

Please kindly help me correct this error.

```
program grid2cube
      implicit none

      integer           maxp, natmax, nskip

      parameter         (maxp = 12000000)
      parameter         (natmax = 1000)

      integer           ipt, isp, ix, iy, iz, i, ip, natoms, np, 
     .                  mesh(3), nspin, Ind, id(3), iix, iiy,
     .                  iiz, ii, length, lb
      integer           is(natmax), izat(natmax)

      character         sysname*70, fnamein*75, fnameout(2)*75, 
     .                  fnamexv*75, paste*74, task*5, fform*12

      double precision              rho(maxp,2), rhot(maxp,2)

      double precision  cell(3,3), xat(natmax,3), cm(3), rt(3),
     .                  delta(3), dr(3), residual

      external  paste, lb

c ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

      read(*,*)
      read(5,*) sysname
      read(5,*) task
      read(5,*) rt(1),rt(2),rt(3)
      read(5,*) nskip
      read(5,*) fform

      fnamexv = paste(sysname,'.XV')
      if (task .eq. 'rho') then
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.RHO')
      else if (task .eq. 'drho') then 
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.DRHO')
      else if (task .eq. 'ldos') then 
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.LDOS')
      else if (task .eq. 'vt') then 
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.VT')
      else if (task .eq. 'vh') then 
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.VH')
      else if (task .eq. 'bader') then 
        fnamein = paste(sysname,'.BADER')
      else
        write(6,*) 'Wrong task'
        write(6,*) 'Accepted values:  rho, drho, ldos, vh, vt, bader'
        write(6,*) '(in lower case!!!!)'
        stop
      endif


      length = lb(fnamein)
      write(6,*) 
      write(6,*) 'Reading grid data from file ',fnamein(1:length)

c read function from the 3D grid --------------------------------------------

      open( unit=1, file=fnamein, form=fform, status='old' )

      if (fform .eq. 'unformatted') then
        read(1) cell
      else if (fform .eq. 'formatted') then
        do ix=1,3
          read(1,*) (cell(iy,ix),iy=1,3)
        enddo
      else
        stop 'ERROR: last input line must be formatted or unformatted'
      endif


      write(6,*) 
      write(6,*) 'Cell vectors'
      write(6,*) 
      write(6,*) cell(1,1),cell(2,1),cell(3,1)
      write(6,*) cell(1,2),cell(2,2),cell(3,2)
      write(6,*) cell(1,3),cell(2,3),cell(3,3)

      residual = 0.0d0
      do ix=1,3
      do iy=ix+1,3
        residual = residual + cell(ix,iy)**2
      enddo
      enddo

      if (residual .gt. 1.0d-6) then
        write(6,*) 
        write(6,*) 'ERROR: this progam can only handle orthogonal cells'
        write(6,*) ' with vectors pointing in the X, Y and Z directions'
        stop
      endif

      if (fform .eq. 'unformatted') then
        read(1) mesh, nspin
      else
        read(1,*) mesh, nspin
      endif

      write(6,*) 
      write(6,*) 'Grid mesh: ',mesh(1),'x',mesh(2),'x',mesh(3)
      write(6,*) 
      write(6,*) 'nspin = ',nspin
      write(6,*) 

      do ix=1,3
        dr(ix)=cell(ix,ix)/mesh(ix)
      enddo

      np = mesh(1) * mesh(2) * mesh(3)
      if (np .gt. maxp) stop 'grid2d: Parameter MAXP too small'
C      read(1) ( (rho(ip,isp), ip = 1, np), isp = 1,nspin)
      do isp=1,nspin
        Ind=0
        if (fform .eq. 'unformatted') then
          do iz=1,mesh(3)
          do iy=1,mesh(2)
            read(1) (rho(Ind+ix,isp),ix=1,mesh(1))
            Ind=Ind+mesh(1)
          enddo
          enddo
        else
          do iz=1,mesh(3)
          do iy=1,mesh(2)
            read(1,'(e15.6)') (rho(Ind+ix,isp),ix=1,mesh(1))
            Ind=Ind+mesh(1)
          enddo
          enddo
        endif
      enddo

C translate cell
      do ix=1,3
        delta(ix) = rt(ix)/dr(ix)
        id(ix) = delta(ix)
        delta(ix) = rt(ix) - id(ix) * dr(ix)
      enddo

      do iz=1,mesh(3)
      do iy=1,mesh(2)
      do ix=1,mesh(1)
        iix=ix+id(1)
        iiy=iy+id(2)
        iiz=iz+id(3)
        if (iix .lt. 1) iix=iix+mesh(1)
        if (iiy .lt. 1) iiy=iiy+mesh(2)
        if (iiz .lt. 1) iiz=iiz+mesh(3)
        if (iix .gt. mesh(1)) iix=iix-mesh(1)
        if (iiy .gt. mesh(2)) iiy=iiy-mesh(2)
        if (iiz .gt. mesh(3)) iiz=iiz-mesh(3)

        if (iix .lt. 1) stop 'ix < 0'
        if (iiy .lt. 1) stop 'iy < 0'
        if (iiz .lt. 1) stop 'iz < 0'
        if (iix .gt. mesh(1)) stop 'ix > cell'
        if (iiy .gt. mesh(2)) stop 'iy > cell'
        if (iiz .gt. mesh(3)) stop 'iz > cell'
        i=ix+(iy-1)*mesh(1)+(iz-1)*mesh(1)*mesh(2)
        ii=iix+(iiy-1)*mesh(1)+(iiz-1)*mesh(1)*mesh(2)
        do isp=1,nspin
          rhot(ii,isp)=rho(i,isp)
        enddo
      enddo
      enddo
      enddo

      close(1)

      open( unit=3, file=fnamexv, status='old', form='formatted')
      read(3,*)
      read(3,*)
      read(3,*)
      read(3,*) natoms
      do i=1,natoms
        read(3,*) is(i),izat(i),(xat(i,ix),ix=1,3)
      enddo

      do i=1,natoms
        do ix=1,3
          xat(i,ix)=xat(i,ix)+rt(ix)-delta(ix)
          if (xat(i,ix) .lt. 0.0) xat(i,ix)=xat(i,ix)+cell(ix,ix)
          if (xat(i,ix) .gt. cell(ix,ix)) 
     .        xat(i,ix)=xat(i,ix)-cell(ix,ix)
        enddo
      enddo
      close(3)



      if (nspin .eq. 1) then
        fnameout(1) = paste(fnamein,'.cube')
      else if (nspin .eq. 2) then
        fnameout(1) = paste(fnamein,'.UP.cube')
        fnameout(2) = paste(fnamein,'.DN.cube')
      else 
        stop 'nspin must be either 1 or 2'
      endif

      do isp=1,nspin

      length = lb(fnameout(isp))
      write(6,*) 'Writing CUBE file ',fnameout(isp)(1:length)

C      open( unit=2, file=fnameout(isp), status='new', form='formatted')
      open( unit=2, file=fnameout(isp), form='formatted')

      length = lb(fnameout(isp))
      write(2,*) fnameout(isp)(1:length)
      write(2,*) fnameout(isp)(1:length)
      write(2,'(i5,4f12.6)') natoms, 0.0,0.0,0.0

      do ix=1,3
        ii = mesh(ix)/nskip
        if (ii*nskip .ne. mesh(ix)) ii = ii+1
        write(2,'(i5,4f12.6)') 
     .    ii,(cell(ix,iy)/ii,iy=1,3)
      enddo

      do i=1,natoms
        write(2,'(i5,4f12.6)') izat(i),0.0,(xat(i,ix),ix=1,3)
      enddo



      do ix=1,mesh(1),nskip
      do iy=1,mesh(2),nskip

        write(2,'(6e13.5)') 
     .  (rhot(ix+(iy-1)*mesh(1)+(iz-1)*mesh(1)*mesh(2),isp), 
     .   iz=1,mesh(3),nskip)

      enddo
      enddo

      close(2)

      enddo

      write(6,*) 

      end


      CHARACTER*(*) FUNCTION PASTE( STR1, STR2 )

C CONCATENATES THE STRINGS STR1 AND STR2 REMOVING BLANKS IN BETWEEN
C Writen by Jose M. Soler

      CHARACTER*(*) STR1, STR2
      DO 10 L = LEN( STR1 ), 1, -1
         IF (STR1(L:L) .NE. ' ') GOTO 20
   10 CONTINUE
   20 PASTE = STR1(1:L)//STR2
      END


      INTEGER FUNCTION LB ( STR1 )

C RETURNS THE SIZE IF STRING STR1 WITH BLANKS REMOVED
C Writen by P. Ordejon from Soler's paste.f

      CHARACTER*(*) STR1
      DO 10 L = LEN( STR1 ), 1, -1
         IF (STR1(L:L) .NE. ' ') GOTO 20
   10 CONTINUE
   20 LB = L
      END
```

Comment: The error message clearly states it is a runtime error when reading from stdin. Indicate which line is line 127 (a READ statement) and how do the read data look like.

Comment: I have read the input file which is a binary with hexdump. The "first" line I can see there is like: 0000000 0048 0000 2294 8ca0 89e5 402b 0000 0000 so,I don't know when the flags are the same why should there be a problem reading the file?!

Comment: **Indicate which line is line 127 (a READ statement)**

Comment: Where did you get the data? Is it from a computer with the same architecture? With the same compiler?

Comment: yes, the same computer and same compiler and all the same architecture.

Comment: **Write which line is line 127 (which READ statement)!**

Comment: Line 127: read(5,*) rt(1),rt(2),rt(3)

Comment: wondering how it could work at all as you do not have OPEN statement for unit=5 before call of read

Comment: @Peter: Because unit=5 == stdin, it's preconnected upon program launch.

Comment: Note that stdin is in formatted mode, trying to read unformatted data is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 3):

The statement at the error line is:

```
read(5,*) rt(1),rt(2),rt(3)
```

This is is a list-directed formatted read. As you indicated in the comment, you are trying to read binary (unformatted) data. That cannot work. The statement above expects formatted, data, that means text with human readable numbers.

Also the pre-connected unit 5 is standard input. It shouldn't work for unformatted data if you first read formatted from it (with `read(5,*) sysname`).

Side note: the number 5 for standard input is not standardized, but is quite a safe assumption in practice. But I would use * instead of 5 anyway.

Response to a comment:
The `(*,*)` also cannot work. Generally, whenever you provide a format, which is the second argument in the parenthesis to read or write, you do formatted i/o. It doesn't matter if the format is * or something different. You cannot read unformatted data this way. You have to open a file for the unformatted read with `form=unformatted` with any possible `access` and read it with:

```
read(file_unit_number) rt(1),rt(2),rt(3)
```

If you cannot read the numbers in the data file as a text you cannot use formatted read.

Comment: yes, I have also tried (*,*) for all the "Read" options. To my surprise, again the same error is produced.

Comment: What I meant was ( * , * ) which was not correctly shown in my comment