# Fortran Print Line Number While Reading Input File

Tags: fortran

I am receiving a formatting error from an input file, and I would like to determine where the formatting error is occurring in the input file.
My question is: Is there a way to print the line number of the input file where the error is occurring in my fortran code?

This is the error I get:

```
fmt: read unexpected character
apparent state: unit 4 named input_file
last format: (6(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X))
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
```

Which means that the code is getting hung up on some line in my input file that doesn't correspond with the above format.

Here is the part of my code where Fortran is reading in the input file:

```
      DO 20  K  = 1,NUMB
      READ(4,200)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
      DO 30 J   = 1,6
      L         = L+1
      ISTO(L,N) = NSTN(J)
      SECT(L,N) = TT(J)
      KWV(L,N)  = IKPS(J)
30    CONTINUE
20    CONTINUE
      KOBS(N)   = NSTM
10    CONTINUE
100   FORMAT(5(I2,X),F6.2,X,F5.2,X,F7.3,X,F6.3,X,F8.3,X,F6.3,
     &       X,F6.2,X,F5.2,X,I3,X,F4.1,X,F5.2,X,F7.3) 
200   FORMAT(6(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X))
      RETURN
      END
```

I'd like to add a line in the above piece of code to identify the current line the code is reading, so that when it gets hung up, I'll know which line contains the error.  Thank you for your help.

Here's what I tried and it's giving me another error:

```
c      READ(4,200)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
  READ(4,200)line
  READ(line,*,iostat=ios) (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
  IF(ios>0)THEN
  WRITE(*,*)'Error Reading Line',line
  STOP
  ENDIF
  INTEGER ios
  CHARACTER*(200)line
```

Comment: Adapt https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315813, as one approach.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble trying to adapt that answer/suggestion.  Would you mind suggesting the best way to adapt that suggestion from the other post?  Thank you.

Comment: Essentially: use `iostat=iostat` for integer `iostat` for each `read` and find out when `iostat.ne.0`.

Comment: I've added edits above, but I'm still running into an error.  Any thoughts on where I screwed up the  'Adaption'?  Thank you.

Comment: You'll need your declarations (which you've put at the bottom) at the top.

Comment: Yes sir, that's the case.  I am still running into an error.  Forgive me for my lack of knowledge in Fortran.  I will revise the above block of code to include the entire block of code, rather than pieces of it.

Comment: I edited the answer to account for your modifications in the question. You simply need to put the debugging write statement in the outer loop of your original program. The last printed index will be the problematic line of data.

Comment: The problem with your adaptation is here : `read(4,200)line`. It must be `read(4,'(a)'))`. The `a` says to read the whole line as a string.  (You should also use your 200 format instead of star on the next line )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an explicit loop to read your data like:

```
      DO 20 J = 1,6
      write (*,*) 'Reading line = ', J
      READ(4,100)  NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J)
20    CONTINUE

100   FORMAT(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X)
```

This way, you will know exactly where it stopped thank to the write statement in the reading loop. Note that I added two new labels, 20 to control the new loop and 100 for the new format statement. Adapt accordingly.

==============

```
      DO 20  K  = 1,NUMB
      WRITE (*,*) 'Reading line = ', K
      READ(4,200)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
      DO 30 J   = 1,6
      L         = L+1
      ISTO(L,N) = NSTN(J)
      SECT(L,N) = TT(J)
      KWV(L,N)  = IKPS(J)
30    CONTINUE
20    CONTINUE
      KOBS(N)   = NSTM
200   FORMAT(6(I3,X,F7.2,X,I2,X))
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Should I be adding this explicit loop below the original READ statement, or should I comment out the original READ statement, the original DO loop, and the Formatting?  Thank you.

Comment: Comment out the original one. This bloc of code is a replacement for your original read. I mean the read that is reading 6 lines at a time.

Comment: Doing a read in a loop is different from doing a read with an implied-do.

Comment: @francescalus, I agree with you. This is a suggestion to which line of data is causing problem. This was the question if I got it right.

Comment: But this will test only the part of each line corresponding to the first three data points.  That is, it reads three numbers from six records, rather than 18 from one.

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to see which line in my input is causing the problem with the 200 Format, which corresponds with 18 numbers (3X6).

Comment: That was a missing piece. You have to add the debuging write statement to the outter loop and keep your original code.

Comment: I edited the answer to account for your modifications in the question. You simply need to put the debugging write statement in the outer loop of your original program. The last printed index will be the problematic line.

Comment: OK awesome.  I will give that a try, and hopefully I'll be able to solve my issue!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I actually wrote to screen another value that was being read in from the input file, to see where it was getting hung up, but I attribute the idea to you.  Many thanks!

Comment: I am glad to help! and happy that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

With a read statement like

```
      READ(4,200)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
```

an error in the input results in (error) termination of the program.  One has no control over this termination, and in particular one can't do further processing.

There are two ways to avoid this termination, and both involve using an additional specifier in the read statement.  One is `iostat=` and the other `err=`.  If either of these is present then an error doesn't result in termination.

With `iostat` (for integer `istat`):

```
      READ(4,200,iostat=istat)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
```

then on an error condition, `istat` will have a (processor-dependent) positive value.  It will be zero when (and only when) there is no error.

With `err` (for some label, say, `991`):

```
      READ(4,200,err=991)  (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
```

Putting all that together, let's imagine an outer loop

```
      DO 100 LINE=1,91959
        READ(4,200,IOSTAT=ISTAT) (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
        IF (ISTAT.NE.0) THEN
          PRINT *, 'It went wrong on line', LINE
          STOP
        END IF
        ...
100   CONTINUE
```

or

```
      DO 100 LINE=1,91959
        READ(4,200,ERR=991) (NSTN(J),TT(J),IKPS(J),J=1,6)
        ...
 100  CONTINUE
      ...
 991  PRINT *, 'It went wrong on line', LINE
      STOP
```

[I couldn't bring myself to write that code like it really was 1980.]