# Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')

Tags: fortran

I am trying to use the code below to read a formatted file and write it into another. However, on running it shows the following error

Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input

```
 $ ./conv.sac.farm < i_conv.farm
 # stn  comp      Delta    Tr-time   Start in record 
  At line 54 of file Main/conv.sac.farm.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
  Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input
```

The source code is as follows

```
PARAMETER (nd0=100000,pi=3.1415926)
      IMPLICIT COMPLEX*8 (Z)
      CHARACTER name*6,comp*6,fname*60,event*20
     -   ,cmp(0:3)*5,fname0*60,charac*15,scode*60
      REAL*8 GFACT(500),PP0(500),depth0
      integer hr0,mnu0,yr,month,day,hr,mnu
      REAL  x(nd0),y(nd0)
      DIMENSION Z(nd0),zpole(50),zero(50)
      data np,cmp/8,'disp.','vel. ','acc. ','orig.'/
      common /tbl/ip(110,14),is(110,14),secp(110,14),secs(110,14)
      read(5,'(a)') event
      read(5,*) alats,alons,depth,hr0,mnu0,sec0,id,delmin,delmax
      depth0=depth
      write(22,'(a,a5,3f7.2,2i3,f6.2)') 
     #            event,cmp(id),alats,alons,depth,hr0,mnu0,sec0
* << J-B travel time table >>
      OPEN(11,FILE='jb.ptime')
      OPEN(12,FILE='jb.stime')
1000  read(11,*,end=1001) n,(ip(n,i),secp(n,i),i=1,14)
      goto 1000
1001  read(12,*,end=1002) n,(is(n,i),secs(n,i),i=1,14)
      goto 1001
1002  continue
      close(11)
      close(12)
* << Geometrical factor >>
      OPEN(15,FILE='jb.table')
      CALL GEOM(GFACT,PP0,depth0)
      close(15)
      nstn=0
      print *,' #   stn  comp      Delta    Tr-time   Start in record'
5     read(5,'(a)') fname
      read(5,'(a)') scode
*     ta=advance of start-time relative the standard P/S arrival
*     du=duration
c
      if(fname.eq.'dummy') goto 90
      read(5,*) ta,du,dt,f1,f2,iph,nr,iuni
      open(1,file=fname)
      READ(1,'(g15.7)') dt0
      read(1,'(/////5g15.7)') dum, alat, alon, elev
      read(1,'(///////5i10)') yr, nday, hr,mnu, nsec
      read(1,'(5i10)') nmsec,ndum,ndum,ndum,nd
      read(1,'(/////)')
      read(1,'(a6,2x,a13)') name,charac
      read(1,'(////)')
```

And so on..
 Line 54 is

```
read(5,*) ta,du,dt,f1,f2,iph,nr,iuni
```

and my  i_conv.farm file is

```
1604151625 Japan
 32.79 130.58    10 16 25 06 1 30 100

II.BORG.00.BH1.A
II.BORG.00
II.BORG.00.BH2.A
II.BORG.00
II.BORG.00.BHZ.A
II.BORG.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1 
II.DGAR.00.BH1.A
II.DGAR.00
II.DGAR.00.BH2.A
II.DGAR.00
II.DGAR.00.BHZ.A
II.DGAR.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1 
II.TAU.00.BH1.A
II.TAU.00
II.TAU.00.BH2.A
II.TAU.00
II.TAU.00.BHZ.A
II.TAU.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1 
II.UOSS.00.BH1.A
II.UOSS.00
II.UOSS.00.BH2.A
II.UOSS.00
II.UOSS.00.BHZ.A
II.UOSS.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1 
II.WRAB.00.BH1.A
II.WRAB.00
II.WRAB.00.BH2.A
II.WRAB.00
II.WRAB.00.BHZ.A
II.WRAB.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1 
IU.AFI.00.BH1.A
IU.AFI.00
IU.AFI.00.BH2.A
IU.AFI.00
IU.AFI.00.BHZ.A
IU.AFI.00
20 120 1
0.002 1 1 1 1
```

I really don't know where the formatted data is not right?

Comment: By my count the code hasn't skipped (or read) all the lines beginning `II.BORG` before it attempts to read the value for `ta` and can't interpret something like `II.BORG.00` as a real number.  I didn't take my shoes and socks off so my counting may be wonky, but do check.

Comment: are you really still stuck on this same problem from over two years ago? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24303045/1004168.  When you tried the answer provided to that question what result did you obtain?

Comment: @agentp He is a different user. You cannot see that, but he tried to ask there in an answer and that answer/question was deleted by a moderator. The answer there is not really a definitive answer to the problem, just a tip how to debug it. (I haven't study the details of the question too much, I tend to care less about these very specific questions about I/O in someone's code and input files.) If some answer on wither of these questions attracts an upvote, we can close them as duplicates. I personally will not upvote any answer just for the sake of it, only if it offers a real solution.

Comment: I'd be inclined to close both. This seems like someone who doesn't know the first thing about what the code is supposed to do asking "please fix this".

Comment: Thanks for the care,and I have too little relevant perl knowledge for that problem,and I have tried the help listed there for testing where it is wrong and  the results are not ideal so I asked here again.@agentp

Answer (score 1):

Let's count the `read(5)`, which I think is read from `stdin`, which in your case would be `i_conv.farm`

```
read(5,'(a)') event
```

This reads "1604151625 Japan" into `event`

```
read(5,*) alats,alons,depth,hr0,mnu0,sec0,id,delmin,delmax
```

This reads the line "32.79 130.58    10 16 25 06 1 30 100" and distributes it over the variables.

Then you make a call to `GEOM`, but I assume that that subroutine doesn't read from `stdin`. Next is

```
read(5,'(a)') fname
```

And this reads am empty line. So there is already something fishy. Next is

```
read(5,'(a)') scode
```

So `scode` becomes "II.BORG.00.BH1.A". Now we come to the read where it finally falls over:

```
read(5,*) ta,du,dt,f1,f2,iph,nr,iuni
```

But the line is "II.BORG.00" -- there's no way to parse that into a number for `ta`.

Looking at the code, it's a mess to debug, and I don't even know what it's supposed to do. Which part of the `i_conv.farm` should be read into which value? If you want to read from standard input, I'd strongly suggest using `read(*,` instead of `read(5,`, because you can't guarantee that 5 will always be the standard input.

At this point, I'd throw my hands into the air, and start completely rewriting at least the file i/o part of the program.

Comment: I am very appreciate for your response in so much detail to teach me where I should pay attention to,It seems that there are something wrong with  the input file,and I will try to debug it.Thanks again!@chw21